# Почему состояние перезаписывает с потерей предыдущих значений?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я делаю загрузку drag-and-drop изображений на сервер, и перед этим отображаю их у себя. Вот как это выглядит (т.е. я перетаскиваю изображения на область(серый квадрат) и отпускаю, после чего происходят все процессы, и нижу серого квадрата отображаются перетащенные фото)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код чтения файлов.

```
function ondropHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (images.length >=5) { return } // проверка кол-ва фото
    let files = [...e.dataTransfer.files]
    files = files.filter(file => (file.type === "image/jpeg" || file.type === "image/png") && file.size < 5242880)
    files.splice(5)
    setFilesSend([...filesSend, files[0]])
    for(let i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            let img = {id:genUUID(), url:e.target.result, type:files[i].type, name: files[i].name}
            setImages([...images, img] ) // вот здесь работает не так как надо
        }        
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Я добавляла по одному изображению и все работала хорошо (фото загружалось и отображалось). Но теперь я захотела добавить возможность перетаскивания нескольких фото. И столкнулась с проблемой, что при изменении состояния **images**, у меня всегда отображается одна картинка (хотя перетаскивала 3 или 5), и так получается, что в цикле при выполнении **setImages([..images, img])** он сохраняет только **img**, а все предыдущие **images** не учитываются. И в итоге в состоянии хранится одна картинка, в следствии чего и отображается она одна. Почему **setImages** просто перезаписывает состояние?  Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй присваивать через callback

```
setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, img])
```

Update:
вообще было бы здорово уменьшить количетво ререндеров до 1

```
function readFileAsText(file){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = function(e){
            resolve({id:genUUID(), url:e.target.result, type:file.type, name: file.name});
        };

        fr.onerror = function(){
            reject(fr);
        };

        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}


if(!files.length) return;

// Store promises in array
for(let i = 0;i < files.length;i++){
    readers.push(readFileAsText(files[i]));
}
                
// Trigger Promises
Promise.all(readers).then((values) => {
    setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, values])
});
```

Comment: но почему мой вариант не работал?

Comment: из за асинхронности image еще не успевает обновится - и во всех случаях ты просто используешь одни и те же данные
вот тут можно подробнее почитать
https://temofeev.ru/info/articles/zametka-o-tom-kak-react-obnovlyaet-sostoyanie/